# Core Data detail view Error

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview

I have been working on an app that has a tableview where users can add information on a seperate ViewController via UITextField. I am now trying to set it up so the user can tap on any given Cell to be able to view the data back on that ViewController or edit it again. Everything is being saved using CoreData.

[image]

Comment: Post full VC code , Seems your task is not String Value,

Comment: What your task array contains?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is you can put the check like this. So that it will never crash or throw the error:-

```
if let sender = sender as? String {
 guest.player = sender
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you once I get back home I’ll try this out!